# How can I detect sensor value drop-outs? (Calculating differences between the rows.)

Tags: sql

Motivation: The table contains sensor values for the UTC. I know that the sensor should return the sampled value after certain period (it can vary a bit). Anyway, there is some critical time period that--when exceeded--indicates a drop-out.

Having really a lot of data, is there a way to detect UTCs when the drop-out happened without using cursor and loop?

In other words, is there a way to select differences between consequent rows without using a loop?

For example (simplified table):

```
UTC                       temperature
2017-09-14 22:15:34       15.6
2017-09-14 22:16:34       15.8
2017-09-14 22:17:34       15.9
2017-09-14 22:18:34       15.9
2017-09-14 22:19:34       15.8
2017-09-14 22:25:50       16.2
2017-09-14 22:26:50       16.3
```

Here the temperature should be sampled each minute. The interval between the 22:19 and 22:25 should be considered a drop-out. Ideally, I would like to get the two UTC's as one result row result of the detected situation.

Actually, there may be some variations of intervals between consequent UTCs from ideal sampling time. That is because the UTC is generated on the SQL server as "now" when the value is inserted. Here the sampled value does not change quickly. It is OK when for some reason few samples are missing.
Anyway, say **5 minutes** is the critical interval. Anything more than that be detected as drop-out.

I am using MS-SQL 2014 if it matters.

Comment: **[edit]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). Do not post code or additional information in comments

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database) are you using? Postgres? Oracle? DB2? Firebird?

Comment: so your expected result is 2017-09-14 22:19:34 and 2017-09-14 22:25:50?

Comment: @FerdinandGaspar: Yes. And it is fairly easy using the explicit loop. I would like to know whether it is possible using SELECT. It is probably possible to join the temporary table with original rows shifted by one. I am searching for more solutions to find the right one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do a self-join and get the difference of previous and current row's utc and determine if it is equal or greater than 5 minutes

```
WITH t AS (
SELECT *, 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY utc) rnum
  FROM t_temp)

SELECT t1.utc,
       t1.temperature,
       t2.utc,
       t2.temperature
  FROM t t1
 INNER JOIN t t2
    ON t1.rnum = t2.rnum - 1
 WHERE DATEDIFF(mi, t1.utc, t2.utc) >= 5
```

Result

```
utc                     temperature utc                     temperature
2017-09-14T22:19:34Z    15.8        2017-09-14T22:25:50Z    16.2
```

or if you want it on different rows, just use UNION ALL

```
WITH t AS (
SELECT *, 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY utc) rnum
  FROM t_temp)

SELECT t1.utc,
       t1.temperature
  FROM t t1
 INNER JOIN t t2
    ON t1.rnum = t2.rnum - 1
 WHERE DATEDIFF(mi, t1.utc, t2.utc) >= 5
 UNION ALL
SELECT t2.utc,
       t2.temperature
  FROM t t1
 INNER JOIN t t2
    ON t1.rnum = t2.rnum - 1
 WHERE DATEDIFF(mi, t1.utc, t2.utc) >= 5
```

Result

```
utc                     temperature
2017-09-14T22:19:34Z    15.8
2017-09-14T22:25:50Z    16.2
```

Comment: Thank you. It is simple and understandable. Anyway, can you comment on whether a temporary table is or is not better than cte, and what conditions would make the difference between the cte vs. #temporary? How can I test the performance or the theoretical performance?